# BigQuery - Failed to parse input string

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp

I have extracted strings from a JSON field in the following format`"2020-07-0217:39:02-04:00"` stored in a column called `time_string`.

When I use the following function `PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%Ez", time_string)` I'm getting a "Failed to parse input string" error for all rows.

If I directly paste a date from `time_string` as the input for the parse function, I'm getting an output.

Query: `SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%Ez", "2020-07-0217:39:02-04:00")`

Output: `2020-07-02 21:39:02 UTC`

I know there are multiple posts with similar issues here. Read through them but was unable to figure this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only explanation I see is - some of your `time_string`s have different format than you expects

To find the, run below

```
#standardSQL
select time_string
from `project.dataset.table`
where SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%Ez", time_string) is null
```

> Update

Looks like some of your values wrapped with quotes

[image]

so use below instead

```
select PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%Ez", trim(time_string, '"'))
```

Comment: I ran your query and I'm getting all the rows that were there in my table as the output. The ````PARSE_TIMESTAMP``` function doesn't appear to be working for any value.
[screenshot](https://share.getcloudapp.com/KouwjwpW)

Comment: please give an example of at least one `time_string` value that came out!

Comment: Sample `time_string` value: "2020-09-2222:36:27-07:00" Like I said in my initial question, if I directly input this in the `parse_timestamp` function I'm getting the output I'm looking for.

Comment: are you sayin that you run the query I provided in my answer and value `2020-09-2222:36:27-07:00` came out? please confirm

Comment: so, i checked the screenshot you provided in your comment (i missed it initially) - so, don't you see that the values that came out are of different format - which is  - they all have extra quotes at the beginning and end - so use `PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S%Ez", trim(time_string, '"'))` instead

Comment: sure. glad we nailed it! :o)

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant,

Thanks for the above solution. It worked for me. But, just curious to know the difference between PARSE_TIMESTAMP and SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP as using SAFE solved my issue.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I have a similar issue where the Date string has / as delimiters. So it is in 2022/11/01 . When I use Parse_Date(%Y%m%d, Date) it returns the error. Appreciate input here. Thanks !